# How can I make this monad stack reusable?

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers

I'm writing an interpreter for a simple programming language. It has two stages: a parser and an evaluator. The parser reads a text file and creates a tree with the expressions, values, etc. It also makes some validations. Here is the monad stack I'm using:

```hs
type Type = IntT | BoolT | CharT
data FunEnv = [String]
data VarEnv = [(String, Type)]
type ParserEnv r = StateT (FunEnv, VarEnv) (Except String) r
```

The functions environment stores the names of defined functions, and the variables environment stores the types of defined variables. As the parser reads the file and finds function or variable definitions, it adds them to the state. The parser can also fail, which is why I'm using the `Except` monad.

After that, comes the evaluator. The evaluator also needs a similar monad stack, but instead of storing the types of the variables, it needs to store the values they are storing:

```hs
type Value = IntV Int | BoolV Bool | CharV Char
data FunEnv = [String]
data VarEnv = [(String, Value)]
type EvaluatorEnv r = StateT (FunEnv, VarEnv) (Except String) r
```

So, in order to be able to reuse the previous stack, I thought of refactoring it to be more general:

```hs
data FunEnv = [String]
type VarEnv a = [(String, a)]
type Env a r = StateT (FunEnv, VarEnv a) (Except String) r
```

Now `FunEnv` and `VarEnv` are more general, so I can define a type for the parser and for the evaluator using the same monad stack:

```hs
type ParserEnv r = Env Type r
type EvaluatorEnv r = Env Value r
```

Even though this complicates a bit the types of the functions that interact with the monad at a low level, it works. However, the problem is that the evaluator has to be able to perform IO actions, so I need the IO monad at the core of my stack. Once again, I can generalize my stack to account for this:

```hs
type Env a m r = StateT (FunEnv, VarEnv a) (ExceptT String m) r
```

As you can notice, I added a parameter `m` which is the monad at the core of the stack, and I'm using `ExceptT` instead of `Except`. Now, I can redefine the parser monad with `Identity` at its core, and the evaluator monad with `IO` at its core:

```hs
type ParserEnv r = Env Type Identity r
type EvaluatorEnv r = Env Value IO r
```

One of the downsides I see in this approach is that I need to use the `mtl` package for the `Identity` monad, but more importantly it complicates the types of low level functions even more. The type of a general function for getting what is associated to a variable would look like this:

```hs
getVariable :: Monad m => String -> Env a m (Maybe a)
```

Maybe I'm overthinking this and my solution is alright, but I would appreciate a second opinion.
Is there a better way to make this monad stack general? Or are the behaviors too different and I should implement it twice separately?

Comment: What you're doing looks totally fine to me.  When dealing with monad transformers, it's pretty common to have multiple type variables — after all, `StateT` has three, one each for the state type, the underlying monad, and the carried value; and `Env` is really no different.

Comment: There's an excellent (but slightly dated) paper that would be relevant reading for you called "Monad Transformers Step by Step" by Grabmuller.  There's an lhs version of the paper at https://github.com/bitemyapp/monad-transformers-step-by-step/blob/master/mt-sbs.lhs, as well as some PDF versions floating around.

Comment: I really liked that article, and I read it many times when I started learning about monads. Thank you both! I guess I was really just overthinking it. Should I remove the question?